# I cannot find signingConfigs DSL container in android studio

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio

I wanted to check my application on emulator but unfortunately logcat showed me an error:" *Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script*.".After that i'm tried to find a solution to this problem and i found  an answer on stackoverflow,however,there are no explanation on where signingConfigs DSL container is.It may seem ridiculous but i'm neophyte on android programming.Please help me!!!
P.S. I'm using Android Studio

Comment: You need to set up the signingConfigs in your build.gradle file for your application module. If you're having trouble getting that to work, please add the relevant file to your question.

Comment: Documentation is here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations

Comment: @XavierDucrohet i did everything as it was written in article that you advised,but,when i focus on the code it states:Cannot resolve symbol"signingConfigs"

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your build.gradle if you can.